# Using edge detector to enhance Preprocess in optical character recognition(ocr)

Tags: java, android, computer-vision, ocr

OCR Optical character recognition

I'm done with the preprocessing: binarization local&global w/o api/libs
and i use tesseract tessbase api for page segmentation and recognition.
the results are almost fine it can recognize about 70% accuracy.

Can i use edge detection( so that it can help to highlight the edges) for preprocess or should i used it for segmentation?
how could I enhance the accuracy..